# How to insert data into foreign key table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys

How do I insert a primary key into a foreign key column.

I am trying to get the `UserID` from `tblUser` and insert it into `tblPurchasedGames` where column name is `UserID`. However I am getting an error which can be seen below the code.

What I have tried so far:

```
private void Btn_AddToLibary_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   sqlConnection.Open();
   SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT into tblPurchasedGames (UserID, GameID)" + "values(@UserID, @GameID)", sqlConnection);
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID","UserID");
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameID","GameID");
   com.ExecuteNonQuery();
   sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'UserID' to data
>   type int.

Tables relationship diagram:
[image]

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Larnu im sorry im a noob

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about on using `AddWithValue` . There are just *known* problems with using it. if you're new, you might as well learn the right way now. :)

Comment: @Larnu ye i knew about it but had completely forgot about it plus this isnt anything that important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the following part you are trying to insert strings onto integer fields:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID","UserID");
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameID","GameID");
```

You can try the following code

```
com.Parameters.Add("@UserID",SqlDbType.Int) = yourUserIDVar;
com.Parameters.Add("@GameID",SqlDbType.Int) = yourGameIDVar;
```

Replace `yourUserIDVar`and `yourGameIdVar`with the variables you want to pass into the method.

Answer (score 1):

You try to add parameter as **strings**, but you should add them as **integers**:

```
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameID", GameID);
```

EDIT:

Here I suppose you have int variables `UserID` and `GameID` which holds foreign key values.

Comment: Which error? Something about type cast? Show us how you obtain `UserID` and `GameID` variables.

Comment: No unless the entity framework class that i have counts.

Comment: error: UserID does not exist in the current context.

Comment: When you type `"UserId"` it treated as string constant (this is the reason for your initial error). But `UserId` means you should have an integer variable which contains a real value for your foreign key. You should describe and initialize it yourself. If you use EF it can be something like `int UserID = User.UserID`

Comment: @Miamy There are already discussions going on to stop using AddWithValue.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your 'UserID' columns is tagged as varchar, and you are trying to insert it into tblPurchasedGames 'UserID' which is int

EDIT: Miamy answers is probably right

Comment: its not varcahr because its a primary key thats literally impossible i even checked

Comment: This is not an answer rather than a comment, you should wait until you get the reputation required for comment. Other wise you should post your answer properly not like comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private void Btn_AddToLibary_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT into tblPurchasedGames (UserID, GameID)" + "values(@UserID, @GameID)", sqlConnection);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID",UserID.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameID",GameID.Text);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
```

You try to add parameter as strings, but you should add them as integers: